# UUID of phone/device - does it need to be secure?

Tags: php, ios, uuid

Didn't see this question specifically, and google turned up a bunch of stuff about URL authentication for privacy concerns unrelated to the UUID specifically.

My question is, in my native iOS app, I am pulling the phone/device's UUID (A9081856-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-6447049167C0). Is it ok to use that UUID in a PHP GET call without "masking" it or obscuring it? Can any harm be done by knowing someone else's UUID of their device?

Just trying to determine if I need to re-think how I pass that data to a PHP script, and a GET is my current simplest option.

Comment: I am not an expert but as theses datas are related to each specific device, it will be better to encrypt datas to avoid to be stoled.

Comment: A device UUID is not a 'secure' identifier. [Any system that uses it as such is fundamentally broken](https://www.nowsecure.com/resources/secure-mobile-development/handling-sensitive-data/limit-use-of-uuid/); and 'sharing' it can be used to violate such systems that use it as a 'secure' id.

Comment: I actually read that article while googling. It states "Apple has recognized both the privacy and security risks of UUID and has removed developer access.", but that was 2014... iOS 8 lets me use identifierForVendor, so I don't know how true that article is. That article doesn't directly speak to whether it needs to be secured or not - only that it's not a good "identifier" of a user. Not really what I'm looking for, but thank you for the input!

Comment: The insecurity with sharing/exposing a/the device-UUID is that some systems might improperly use it as a 'secure' token that binds a specific user; when it is not and does not. `identifierForVendor` is not prone to this - on the same scale, because of vendor segregation, although it should still *not* be treated as a security identifier - because *each [app] vendor* will get a different ID (per user). This makes it a "VUID" and not a device-UUID.

Comment: Going further the `identifierForAdvertising` is - you guessed it - *not* to be used as a security token! It is similar to a/the device UUID in that it is specific-per-device, but differs in that it is effectively associated with the device's linked account (and thus offers segregation between different people owning the device).

Comment: So the 'security' problem with exposing any such token is in systems that improperly use it (including the current system that consumes it). Although privacy breaches and/or tracking could also be abused.

Comment: I'm looking into hashing the UUID using PHP 5.5's new bcrypt functions, storing that along-side the UUID, and using the hashed UUID in my URL calls. This "feels" more secure/private, but still not 100% clear on whether or not KNOWING a UUID is inherently insecure.